# div positioning on the website, how to position divs without using "top"

Tags: css, html, positioning, block

I have a problem with positioning divs on my page, I don't want to use top:50px; because I want to have comments in there as well so here comes my question is there any other way to position divs apart from "top" such as display:block in list styles?
thank you so much for any help!

Comment: position how/where? there's lots of ways of doing it, but since you don't say HOW you want something positioned, or show an example of your desired layout, we can't exactly help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs will appear naturally in the DOM flow. They will take up 100% of the width of their parent container by default and will base their height from the non-floated content within them. Use `margin`s to space them out accordingly. By default they have `position:static`. If you want list styles, use `<li>` which are `display:list-item` and not `display:block`.

Example:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="comments"> Some really long comments </div>
<div class="foo"> Something that should appear below the comments </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.foo {
    margin-top : 50px;
}
```

Comment: which position should i use ? absolute or relativE?

Comment: I'm normally using absolute but it overfloat divs my footer overfloated my navigation on the top

Comment: Ok touche. I'm mixing up block level elements with `display:block`, which are not `<li>` as I intended to say.

Comment: Fair enough - just wanted to let you know :)